# Laravel & axios install on other subdomain CORS issue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, laravel-8

[Laravel 8, vue 2, axios]

I have a vue app installed on app.subdomain.domain.com and the laravel backend on subdomain.domain.com. All working fine.

I created another parallel install, on app.subdomain2.domain.com and laravel on subdomain2.domain.com, and i keep getting CORS issues even though i am using same vue frontend and same laravel backend.

I installed the backend using the same repo, git pull (there is only one branch), and deployed the same js files. I even made some changes to test and pushed to both installs and first one is still working fine, second is not.

Axios from what i see is good, backend is just not adding the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.

Tried configuring the cors, added both subdomains on the trusted array, nothing works.

Second install done by doing a git checkout and then composer install.

Am i doing something wrong ?! Going nuts here.

PS laravel install came with \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class

LATER EDIT: on second install, axios does not add any authorization header (it sets it after login, but on install 1 it sends authorization blank, on install 2 doesn't send it at all) -- not sure if this can be an issue or not...

UPDATE: Looking closer on the requests, the OPTIONS has cors headers... the POST request following up the options has not... what the hell

Answer (score 0):

I would say as a first thing to check, see if the APP_URL in the .env file is set to the correct subdomain. Laravel uses this path in various places, and perhaps you're still using the one from the old application which could cause the CORS problem.

Comment: on both installs its set as 'http://localhost' - i will change to https://install.subdomain.com now, but i am not sure that is the problem. I have updated the question with what i could notice with axios